# how to fix the error ( bad file des ) in sass

Tags: sass

Can anyone tell me what this problem is and how to solve it?

`C:\Users\2nguy\Documents\GitHub\WEB>sass style.scss style.css --watch
bad file des

Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.`

I have tried reviewing and running Sass right in the folder containing the SCSS and CSS files, but the problem is still not solved.